# Organizational heirarchy in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have scenario here where the organizational hierarchy is unstructured in AD. Is it possible to define a fresh organization structure in SharePoint 2010, so that i can use the information internally in the intranet site?